# Installing Snaphu on Mac OSX Big Sur ZSH

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, macos

Snaphu is a script that unwraps complex Radar images. The compressed zip setup file can be downloaded from standford website. It should be installed using the zsh terminal and must be copied to system binareis(bin).
I am on Mac OS Big Sur and I extract the snaphu zip on desktop
next I open terminal and write this command.
`cd Desktop/snaphu/src` and then
`sudo make instal`
The installation starts and returned with an error the man/man1 path doesn't exist
So i manually created the path `sudo mkdir usr/local/man man1`

This time when I run the setup again no error shows but when I write `which snaphu` or `whereis snaphu` nothing shows.

Please guide me in installation of snaphu.
[image]

Comment: As it's copied snaphu to /usr/local/bin, try invoking it with command `/usr/local/bin/snaphu` ?

Comment: Do you have `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`. If so, try `rehash` to instruct `zsh` to re-investigate the `$PATH` directories. Then try `snaphu` again.

Answer (score 0):

macOS Big Sur now uses a root read only file system I see no mention of taking any steps to change this to allow the installation of this software.